# Edit page pop up is not working after button click in angular 6 when trying to edit

Tags: angular, microsoft-adal-angular6

I am working in CRUD in angular 6.
My job is to click edit button in the table where data is populated and then popup window show and edit it and table gets updated using angular 6.

Please help, thanks in advance.

I tried adding button as below

popup show open but not

HTML Code:

```
<td class="tbl2"> 
  <button type="button" (click)="OnClickFunction(employee.id)" class="btn btn-info" matTooltip="Click Edit Button">
   Edit
  </button> 
</td>
```

TS Code:

```
OnClickFunction(employeeId: string) { 
  alert('move to Edit page'); 
  this.router.navigate(['/edit/'+employeeId]); 
}
```

Comment: Please explain the question well! Where is that Edit Component Code? What is Not working? What is current behavior?

Comment: Add all the code in the question itself

Comment: Hi,
I have employee.component.html page where I have the button click and onclick() is there in ts file. now I have to click button and it should trigger popuup page to edit.

Comment: Can you post all related code in the question?

Comment: I can help but first, you need to show the code of Employee Component and Edit Component

Comment: employee.component.html
<td class="tbl2">
  <button type="button" (click)="OnClickFunction(employee.id)" class="btn btn-info" matTooltip="Click Edit Button">Edit</button>
</td>
<td class="tbl2">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" matTooltip="Click Delete Button" (click)="deleteEmployee(employee.id)">Delete</button>
</td>
</tr>

Comment: I really unable to understand what you are trying. Can you share the anydesk Id?

Comment: I just want new page or popup to open, when I click edit button. So i did not write any code.Provide watsup. I will share picture of page

Comment: I need to see the code, share your screen! AnyDesk or TeamViewer

Comment: I do not have any, Please let me know any example to do so, by which I can proceed. I can't share my desktop for security reasons

Comment: Well! Here is the link:https://medium.com/@nacojohn/implement-angular-material-dialog-in-your-project-486c7c2f7f5d

Comment: hey there is one dependency available for a popup, I think you have to use that rather manual cade and that package is ngx-smart-modal

Comment: hi,
tried it not working @ Pavan Nagadiya

Answer (score 0):

> Component Code
>   `constructor(private data: DataService, public dialog: MatDialog){ }`

`openDialog(): void {
      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(UserProfileComponent, {
      height: '500px',
      width: '400px',
      data: {UserInfo : this.authRslt }
    });`

> Html

```
<button (click)="openDialog()">Edit</button>
(You can pass particular id in click event)
```

Comment: I will try and let you know, do I need to load any npm package to do this? any example with link is well appreciated, my friend.

Comment: Did not work for me, it is just staying in same page.